# Getting asked if I want to allow or deny incoming connections on the google chrome helper app every time I launch chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firewall

I have clicked deny everytime, and I have checked that the firewall rule states block. Yet it keeps appearing. I realize at this point that I am actually unsure what this dialog window is asking. ie is it saying that an incoming connection is being attempted, and whether I want to accept it, or is it just asking in general whether I want to allow it?

If it's the former, considering this happens on two different networks for the same device, I can't think of any way in which that should be possible.

Is there a way to determine what connection is being attempted, or has anyone else had this start over the last month or so?

Edit: I have found a few other posts related to this, so I don't think this is an isolated issue.

Edit 2: Its in the stats block, but if I check the rules using the terminal it isn't there.

Edit 3: Disabled all my extensions and then rebooted, doesn't do it with them all disabled, but I can't figure out why it would need to verify itself if they are enabled, and none of these are odd extensions:

- Privacy Badger
- Https everywhere
- Ublock Origin
- Umatrix

I'll also add that after disabling them all and starting chrome, the re-enabling them didn't seem to trigger the dialog window.

Edit 3: Ok as far as I can tell, after disabling and re-enabling extensions, Privacy Badger is the one that is triggering this, although I have no idea why.

Comment: Chrome or Chromium? Which version? Which version of MacOS? Can you kindly check the signature by running the following command in Terminal: _codesign --verify -vv /Applications/Chromium.app_ ?

Comment: Try to clear the extended file attributes of app bundle and its internal files you can use via the terminal: _xattr -cr out/Default/Chromium.app_ and then apply ad-hoc signing to the whole app bundle: _codesign --force --deep --sign - out/Default/Chromium.app_

Comment: [there is actually a thread here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394986/macos-firewall-do-you-want-the-application-google-chrome-app-to-accept-incom) on the subject which suggest this (and an [additional solution](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-macos/issues/17) which suggest to replace the code signature).

Comment: @slartibartfast Chrome. Current version is 103.0.5060.53, but it was around 99.0.4844 when this started. On Montenery 12.4, but probably whatever version was out in march when this started.

Comment: @slartibartfast it keeps saying the command verify isn't found. Do I need to run it as sudo? Should the file path for the app not be different given its the chrome helper app, not chromium.app ?

Comment: @slartibartfast Also, does this mean that this has nothing to do with incoming connections? I am still unsure whether or not this message only appears if a connection is attempted or not? I thought not, as I have no port forwarding on my network set up, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Chrome/Chrome helper keeps on prompting you for incoming network connections permission - this has nothing to do with an actual, in this moment, occuring connection - you just have to give firewall permission to the program.

Comment: you run it for Chrome - if that’s what you use.I personally prefer Chromium 

Comment: for the signature check using _codesign_  you have to adopt the path to your Chrome location.

Comment: In the terminal use to check the signature: _codesign --verify -vv /Applications/Chrome.app_ - assuming Chrome is installed in /Applications

Comment: Ok so it states it satisfies the designated requirements. I then went into the package contents and looked at the helper app, and it does as well.

Comment: to clear the extended file attributes of app bundle and its internal files you can use via the terminal: _xattr -cr out/Default/Chrome.app_ and then apply ad-hoc signing to the whole app bundle: _codesign --force --deep --sign - out/Default/Chrome.app_

Comment: that should fix the issues on start up. 

Comment: @slartibartfast If the rule exists in the system preferences section, then why does it ask for it every time on launch?

Comment: The reason is that some apps check their own integrity when they are opened without using code signing. If the firewall recognizes such an app it doesn't sign it. Instead, the "Allow or Deny" dialog appears every time the app is opened. This can be avoided by upgrading to a version of the app that is signed by its developer. [See Apple Support on app firewall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642).

Comment: you can wait for a new version by Google, or allow incoming connections each time, …. or you clear the extended file attributes and force a codesign for the whole app bundle. 

Comment: @slartibartfast so even though the app is signed correctly, according to codesign, it's doing it itself now, so the dialog is always asked for? How come this has only became a problem now, given the post your linked about chromium is from 2019, yet my firewall rules have always been this strict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137538/discussion-between-slartibartfast-and-gaussstrife).