# Firewall bug; socket programming

Tags: network, security, firewall

I am seeking a work-around for a bug in MacOS 12.4. I write C++ programs that create TCP/IP listening sockets. When I launch one of them, I see an error dialog containing language

> Do you want the application “xxxxxx” to accept incoming network connections?

> Clicking Deny may limit the application’s behavior. This setting can be changed in the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences.

I click the button **Allow**, but the next time I launch the same program, I see the same error dialog. I have an unpleasant work-around: I restart the computer.

I am not sure whether the bug is the repeated appearance of the error dialog, or the fact that it ceases to appear after I reboot.

I am not interested in partially disabling system integrity protection with **csrutil**, that would be an unnecessary security risk.

I am thinking that there is probably a process that I can kill instead of rebooting the computer, but I haven't found it yet.

Any suggestions?

Comment: from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642):
Some apps check their own integrity when they are opened without using code signing. If the firewall recognizes such an app it doesn't sign it. Instead, it the "Allow or Deny" dialog appears every time the app is opened. This can be avoided by upgrading to a version of the app that is signed by its developer.

Comment: I’m participating in a related discussion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441744/getting-asked-if-i-want-to-allow-or-deny-incoming-connections-on-the-google-chro).