# Firewall keeps setting an incoming connection to allow for com.google.Chrome.helper despite being set to block

Tags: network, firewall, ventura

A few months ago, I made [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441744/getting-asked-if-i-want-to-allow-or-deny-incoming-connections-on-the-google-chro), asking why the allow or deny dialogue was appearing every time chrome was opened. Everyone stated that this only happens every time an app is opened if it's self signing, so the OS needs to ask everytime. After a bit of experimentation, I narrowed down the culprit to the Privacy Badger extension, as this didn't occur if it was disabled. The dialogue window stopped about a month ago, just when an update was released, so I assumed this had addressed the problem.

However, having just updated to Ventura today, I checked the firewall options, and it's now set to allow, where previously it was set to block, and never changed. Moreover, even setting it to allow, the dialogue always came up before.

Now, the dialogue still isn't appearing, but no matter how many times I change the setting to block, if I exit settings and go back in, it's set to allow again, for some reason. Any ideas what could be going on here? How is it changing back everytime?